# Django development server inaccessible from the internet

Tags: python, django, remote-access

I'm running a Django development server with

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

It is perfectly accessible from the local machine, but not from the outer world. 
Windows 8.1, Python 3.4.3, Django 1.8.4.

I've tried a different port (7500, 50001) and allowing the port explicitly at Windows Firewall (through Inbound Rules).
I've also run the server on a different machine (AWS EC2) with the port allowed there, same result.

Netstat says that the program is listening on the specified port, so theoretically it should be working.
My machine is also in the ALLOWED HOSTS list in settings.py.

I know the development server is not safe enough to be used in production, but I'm doing a small short-term thing that isn't worth bothering with proper deployment. So, any ideas what can be the problem?

Comment: This has nothing to do with neither Python nor Django. Rather with how you are trying to access your machine through the network.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger, typing IP:port in the browser. Is there a better way?

Comment: I was more thinking about router parameters. Does it forward requests to your_ip:8000 to the computer running the server? I’m a bit more worried about EC2 since [it should work there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865621/connecting-to-ec2-django-development-server)

Comment: Yep that's what I thought as well, that's why I tried EC2. 
From the answer you mentioned, I tried telnet and it worked, so it's most likely a connection problem. But since the firewall keeps the port open and so does the security group, the question remains.

Answer (score 0):

In my box which is not windows but, in that case, I think it does not make a difference I searched for my ip with the command `ifconfig`:

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet     
          inet addr:172.16.0.2  Bcast:172.16.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:f2ff:fef4:678c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:73452 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:52360 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:80778194 (77.0 MiB)  TX bytes:5084041 (4.8 MiB)
```

Then, tried to start the server with the intention to listen at that ip:

`./manage.py runserver 172.16.0.2:8000`

The port :8000 is open at my firewall, and it worked.

The most probable is that the equivalent command in windows is called [ipconfig](http://ss64.com/nt/ipconfig.html).

In order to reach the server from the outer world ([not recommended for any reason](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/)) checkout for the term "[port forwarding](http://www.dataturbine.org/content/firewalls)" to perform in your firewall towards the internal IP.

Comment: I believe that ipconfig gives you the private IP, thus it works only locally as well.

Comment: If you want to reach it from the hard-core outside network, you have to open the relevant port of the modem and perform a port forwarding to the private IP. I would [not do that, for any reason](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/). You should better setup nginx - supervisor - gunicorn before the port forwarding part and set ```DEBUG = False```.