# Access Django App on AWS ec2 host

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

This issue might seem very trivial but please try to suggest a solution for this if possible. 
I have deployed a django App on AWS ec2 host and I am able to run the following command successfully.

```
(venv)[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx abc]$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 03, 2016 - 13:15:31
Django version 1.7.1, using settings 'abc.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

But I am not able to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/ from the browser. 
On googling it's suggesting to use nginx or gunicorn. I am not sure if nginx, gunicorn etc. are to be used for this.

Can someone please let me know how can this be accessed from browser ? 
Thanks,

Comment: You **must not** deploy using the dev runserver. This is mentioned *everywhere* in the Django documentation, along with a full explanation on how you actually should deploy. Please read it.

Comment: If your ec2 instance ip is 68.68.68.68 then you need to run python manage.py runserver 68.68.68.68:8000 and then access that address in your browser. 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address, which means is your own pc, not the ec2 instance

Comment: I am now trying: python manage.py runserver 123.45.67.89:8000 from Terminal. But on hitting this in the browser, it is taking forever to load this page. And After few minutes, it stops loading at all.

Answer (score 12):

You need to open HTTP port in AWS instance menu.(all ports except ssh closed in AWS)
Go to your console.aws.amazon.com, then pick your instance and go to last menu item "security groups". It lauch wizard, click on "Inbound" in bottom menu, then "edit", and add HTTP or any port what you want :)
And be sure you using your public AWS IP, to open in browser

Add some screen for you, hope it help:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: so you need only lauch-wizard of incance that you run django, and add HTTP and 8000 if you want, here. Add rule HTTP, Add rule "custom tcp port" , TCP, port range 8000, and source anywhere. Then "save" should work

Comment: just runserver like local host, 127.0.0.1:8000 and then in browser enter your public IP

Answer (score 5):

In order to archive this all you need to do 3 simple steps.

1. Go to the EC2 Console and open up the security group of your instance. go to inbound tab.
   click Edit and then press add rule...add entry with type of Custom TCP Rule and port 8000..
2. Go to your Django project,your app and open up the settings.py script. List your IPv4 address in the allowed_hosts section.. Ex : ALLOWED_HOSTS=['public IPv4']'
3. Now in the console run command python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000...

Open any web browser(from any device) and open the link 'public IPv4':8000

No need any app servers like Apache, NginX..

Comment: I follow steps mentioned by @Gihan wiand it worked when I run runserver command with putty but when I  close putty then it stops working. I really want to know what do I need to run django project on the server ?

Answer (score 0):

@Baterson is right. You should open port 8000 for your server first.

Official document is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html . It is highly detailed.