# unable to access Django server running on ubuntu instance AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have Django project running on AWS with following configuration

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

aws security group configured to **TCP 8000** to allow access from anywhere but am getting timeout when i access server using public ip **xxx.xxx.xxx:8000** even tried with public dns but not connecting to django.when i check netstat its fine

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

i tried after allowing port but no succcess

```
sudo ufw allow 8000
```

when i validate with port checker for  **xxx.xxx.xxx:8000** is seems to be open 
but curiously my **apache2** at **80** is accessible using ip  address

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to EC2 Django development Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865621/connecting-to-ec2-django-development-server)

Comment: I tried all solutions listed there but as i said i can access apache2 at port 80 but getting timeout for port 8000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify your Network Access Control List applied at a subnet level to see if the appropriate traffic is allowed.

Comment: yes its allowed to access from anywhere and even my local machine firewall is allowed to access port 8000